# Why are my Heroku pipeline review apps failing to build with the error: ActiveSupport::EncryptedFile::MissingKeyError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, pipeline

I am using Heroku Pipeline. My staging app is the parent app for my review apps so the environment variables are the same.

My staging app builds every time, no issues there. But, all of my review apps fail to build. The issue seems to be that the review app is missing the encryption key.

I've run `heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=##### -a my-app-staging-pr-99` to set the master key for the review app, but I still get the same build error.

Note: 
- I'm using Rails 5.2.3 with credentials
- I have `config.read_encrypted_secrets = true` in my *production.rb*
- I have my `secret_key_base set in my *credentials.yml*

See the logs below:

Logs:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       ActiveSupport::EncryptedFile::MissingKeyError: Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:96:in `handle_missing_key'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:37:in `key'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:41:in `read'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missing'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/config/environments/production.rb:102:in `block in <main>'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `configure'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:602:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `block in <class:Engine>'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_0ef8f846f0fdc1456a3e91ed8dc095e6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

app.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postdeploy": "rails db:migrate"
  }
}
```

I've been trying to fix this issue for weeks now and I've not been able to figure it out. I'm a newbie, so I apologise if I've missed something obvious here.

Comment: Could you check if in your production.rb you have ```config.read_encrypted_secrets = true``` and also in your secrets.yml ```production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>``` ?

Comment: I have both `config.read_encrypted_secrets = true` in my _production.rb_ and my `secret_key_base` in my _credentials.yml_

Comment: I would try renaming ```credentials.yml``` to ```secrets.yml```. Another attempt would be renaming ```credentials.yml``` to ```credentials.yml.enc``` and set ```config.read_encrypted_secrets = false```

Answer (score 1):

> One way would be to Add `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` to environment variables of
>   your staging app. Then in your review apps, you can inherit it from
>   staging app.

Generate the key by executing

```
rake secret
```

in your project directory

You can use the following command to set the [config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) variable on your staging app

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<KEY GENERATED BY rake secret> -a my-app-staging
```

Now in your [app.json](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#the-app-json-file), you can add

```
"env": {
    "RAILS_MASTER_KEY": {
     "required": true
}
```

In this way, every newly created review app will take its `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` from staging app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I fixed this by using the key in my _master.key_ file as my config variable, not the `rake secret` code. I also added RAILS_MASTER_KEY to my credentials. Once I made those two changes, I updated my _app.json_ as you've suggested and the review app built successfully. If the `rake secret` part worked I'd accept your answer, but it isn't the exact the process that I followed.